# "collapse all" all nodes in one click in firefox or chrome

Tags: xml, google-chrome-extension, xml-parsing, firefox-addon, xml-visualizer

Any way to "collapse all" all nodes in one click in firefox or chrome and then able to search a node's name and then quickly see its path/tree of parent nodes? First collapse not just top node, but all child nodes, and when I search for a node then it opens only that tree of nodes. I want this because I search a node in a big xml file. The node is present many times under different paths of parent nodes and I need to see the path of the node where ever it appears. Right now I have to manually traverse whole file and collapse many times to find all paths of that node that is present many times in a file. Any quick way of doing it?

Comment: You can write a code snippet which automatically clicks on all "Collapse" icons. This takes just a few lines, and can be implemented as a bookmarklet.

Comment: I will prefer a ready-made plugin/add-on first before writing code. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Chrome XML Viewer extension? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xv-%E2%80%94-xml-viewer/eeocglpgjdpaefaedpblffpeebgmgddk?hl=en

Comment: Related question: [Better XML viewing in Firefox](/q/972914)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To collapse all XML nodes in Chrome, execute this in your JavaScript console

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("button collapse-button");
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].click();
}
```

Comment: One liner:    

`Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("collapse-button")).forEach(el => el.click())`

Comment: fix for latest chrome:

`Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("folder-button fold")).forEach(el => el.click())`

Answer (score 4):

If firefox or chrome are not a strict requirement, I suggest [geany](http://www.geany.org/), in particular its *pretty-printer plugin*.
With it you can simply format the file in a human-friendly way, fold and un-fold all elements in a single click and so on.

If you are on debian or ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugin-prettyprinter
```

Comment: I installed geany but couldn't manage to fold all elements with one click.

Comment: Open your XML file, then click `Tools->PrettyPrinter XML`. Finally, try with `Fold All` and `Unfold All` under `Document`. I'm using geany-1.38

Comment: works to some extent. I have a file with 320000 lines. After folding I cannot see the end of the document, in fact not further than 36000 lines. Geany v1.38. EDIT: Its getting stuck on a CDATA